# How to bind fieldset value

Tags: javascript, extjs

For some strange reason I'm unable to bind value for a [fieldset](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/Ext.form.FieldSet.html#methods) with `checkboxToggle` property set to `true`. So, its config looks like so:

```
xtype: "fieldset",
title: "Box",
checkboxName: "bounding_box",            
checkboxToggle: true,
bind: {
    collapsed: "{!rec.bounding_box}"
} // results in error message: TypeError: this[c._config.names.set] is not a function
// bind: "{!rec.bounding_box}" does not work either
```

So, the code above does not work. However, the very same technique works great with simple `checkbox` field:

```
xtype: "checkbox",
fieldLabel: "Show label",                
name: "show_label",
bind: "{rec.show_label}"
```

What is wrong with that and how can I fix it?

Comment: I should add, that in a model both fields are of `bool` type.

Comment: Well, it looks like a bug. According to documentation `fieldset` does not have `expanded` property. However, when we bind it like `bind:{expanded:'{rec.bounding_box}'}`, then it works. However, when we bind `collapsed` property - it does not work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're running in a debug build you'll get an error message saying that it can't bind because there is no setCollapsed method on fieldset. You can add it pretty easily:

```
Ext.define('AddSetCollapsed', {
    override: 'Ext.form.FieldSet',

    setCollapsed: function(collapsed) {
        if (collapsed) { 
            this.collapse();
        } else {
            this.expand();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I found another solution - to use `expanded` property, which however is not documented.

Comment: Another problem is that this binding works only in one direction. So, when we change `fieldset` state from `collapsed` to `expanded`, the corresponding property of the record wil not change. So, it seems like ExtJS needs some fixes.